# How to pass an array of object from javascript to webAssembly

Tags: javascript, node.js, webassembly

I know it is possible to pass arrays of integer to web assembly using something like this :

```js
const bin = ...; // WebAssembly binary, I assume below that it imports a memory from module "imports", field "memory".
const module = new WebAssembly.Module(bin);
const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 2 }); // Size is in pages.
const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module, { imports: { memory: memory } });
const arrayBuffer = memory.buffer;
const buffer = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
```

I have read a lot of documentation and some questions that looks like what I was looking for :

- [How to pass an array of objects to WebAssembly and convert it to a vector of structs with wasm-bindgen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52796222/how-to-pass-an-array-of-objects-to-webassembly-and-convert-it-to-a-vector-of-str)
- [Pass a JavaScript array as argument to a WebAssembly function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875728/pass-a-javascript-array-as-argument-to-a-webassembly-function)
- https://becominghuman.ai/passing-and-returning-webassembly-array-parameters-a0f572c65d97
- https://rob-blackbourn.github.io/blog/webassembly/wasm/array/arrays/javascript/c/2020/06/07/wasm-arrays.html

And yet none of those answered my question.

here is a small example of AssemblyScript that describe the kind of function I would like to use :

```js
class Dummy {
  constructor()
}

export function getDummy(): Dummy {
   return new Dummy();
}

export function workWithDummy(dummies: Dummy[] = []) {
  // do something
}
```

and in the javaScript code :

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const {resolve} = require('../utils/utils.js');
const env = {
    abort: (message, filename, line, column) => {
        throw new Error(`${message} in ${filename} at ${line}:${column}`);
    }
};

module.exports = fs.promises.readFile(resolve('parser.wasm')).then(buffer => {
    return WebAssembly.instantiate(buffer, {env: env}).then(wasmModule => {
       const module = wasmModule.instance.exports;
       module.workWithDummy([module.getDummy()]); //won't work
    });
});
```

I am running this code in nodeJs `18.1.0`

To sum up my question is : how to make this line work ?
`module.workWithDummy([module.getDummy()]); //won't work`